# Problem load data from playerpref

Tags: unity

So I want to make a merge idle game, but I have a problem loading data from `playerprefs`, I have an item that I bought from the store so `obj counts` are increasing but at the same time I want to check another item bought from the store, for example, I buy `obj1` twice, and `obj2` 3 times so  `obj counts` are total of those items 2+3=5.

### What I've tried:

- I'm using for loop for that, but I am confused about how to check for another item.
- using a nested loop, still doesn't work.

### Conditions have met:

- when I bought from the store the `obj count` increased.
- when the object merged `obj count` decreased;
- save current object with `playerprefs.set("currItemBought+index,itemBought),`
- save current current obj index when buy obj.

### What I want:

- every time I start the game again I load data from the playerprefs then the object that spawns must be the same from I bought for example when I buy obj2 twice then when re-start, obj2 must spawn twice, or another example when I buy `obj1` once and `obj2` 3 times so when re-start must spawn `obj1` once and `obj2` 3 times so total `obj count` is 4.

### Preview:

https://youtu.be/vCi0I-YFwfQ

### My Script:

**Load Data**

```cs
    //load Data
    public void LoadData()
    {

        if (PlayerPrefs.HasKey("objCount"))
        {
            // get tier to save 

            objCount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("objCount");
            currHighesTier = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("tier");

            Debug.Log(objCount);
            Debug.Log("tier: " + currHighesTier);

            for (int i = 0; i < objCount; i++)
            {
                if (currHighesTier == i)
                {
                    SpawnObject(currHighesTier);

                }
                else
                {
                    SpawnObject(0);
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            objCount = 1;
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("objCount", objCount);

            SpawnObject(0);
        }
    }
```

**Buy Item**

```cs
public void Buy_Object(int index)
    {
        currCharacter = UI_Manager.instance.characterDB.GetCharacter(index);

        for (int i = 0; i < UI_Manager.instance.shopItemsContainer.childCount; i++)
        {
            if (index == i)
            {
                if (Coin >= characters.characters[index].basePrice * (UI_Manager.instance.shopItemsContainer.GetChild(index).GetComponent<CharacterItemUI>().itemBought + 1))
                {
                    objCount++;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("objCount", objCount);

                    Add_Coin(-characters.characters[index].basePrice * (UI_Manager.instance.shopItemsContainer.GetChild(index).GetComponent<CharacterItemUI>().itemBought + 1));

                    UI_Manager.instance.shopItemsContainer.GetChild(index).GetComponent<CharacterItemUI>().itemBought++;
                    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("currItemBough" + index, UI_Manager.instance.shopItemsContainer.GetChild(index).GetComponent<CharacterItemUI>().itemBought);

                    SpawnObject(index);

                }
                else
                {
                    Debug.Log("Not enough coin");
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

**Evolve when merging**

```cs
private void Evolve()
    {
        //Set object count
        GameManager.instance.objCount--;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("objCount", GameManager.instance.objCount);

        UI_Manager.instance.shopItemsContainer.GetChild(tier).GetComponent<CharacterItemUI>().itemBought--;
        PlayerPrefs.SetInt("currItemBough" + tier, UI_Manager.instance.shopItemsContainer.GetChild(tier).GetComponent<CharacterItemUI>().itemBought);

        evolve_particle.Play();

        LevelProgressUI.Instance.AddXP((tier + 1) * 25);

        tier++;

        gameObject.name = "Obj" + tier;

        GameManager.instance.CheckTier(tier);

        SetObject();
    }
```

**Check Tier**

```cs
 public void CheckTier(int tier)
    {
        if (tier > highestTier)
        {
            highestTier = tier;

            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tier", highestTier);

            StartCoroutine(UI_Manager.instance.NewTier());

            characters.characters[tier].isUnlocked = true;

            UI_Manager.instance.UpdateUI(tier);
        }
        else
        {
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("tier", tier);
        }
    }
```

`Sorry for the preview I use youtube due to 1-minute videos.
from the video when I restart the game the obj that was bought twice only spawned once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main error is, you do not iterate over all stored objects. `objCount` has the total amount stored which is not really helpful for loading the data.

Here is a small example how you could improve your LoadData. `Obj` is not really helpful as a description. And `PlayerPrefs.getInt` has an overload where the second parameter is the default value that you get when the key does not exists.

```
enum Spawnable {Seed, Sprout, Flower, Tree}

public void Start() {
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Item_" + Spawnable.Seed, 3);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Item_" + Spawnable.Sprout, 1);
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Item_" + Spawnable.Tree, 2);
    LoadData();
}

void LoadData() {
    Spawnable highestTier = 0;
    int totalSpawnCount = 0;
    foreach (Spawnable toSpawn in Enum.GetValues(typeof(Spawnable)).Cast<Spawnable>()) {
        int spawnAmount = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Item_" + toSpawn, 0);
        highestTier = spawnAmount > 0 ? toSpawn : highestTier;
        for (int amount = 1; amount <= spawnAmount; amount++) {
            Debug.Log(toSpawn);
            totalSpawnCount++;
        }
    }
    Debug.LogFormat("Highest Tier is {0}", highestTier);
    Debug.LogFormat("Total amount of spawned items is: {0}", totalSpawnCount);
}
```

The improvement is, all your objects are in order in a descriptive list and your evolve function might benefit from it as well.

The initial data is set as example in `Start` but it is missing the `Flower` to demonstrate how missing values are handled. The console is telling you how many objects are spawned from each type, you can just switch it to your own instantiate logic.